# What will happen when Identity column value reach maximum(2^63-1) in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rdbms

We have recently started working on snowflake. We have a few tables with an identity column in snowflake. These tables are staging tables and We are truncating them in every execution. Recently, We noticed that the identity column does not get reset during truncate.

In some databases, like MS SQL server, identity columns get reset in truncate operation.

My question is, Does the identity column get reset when it reaches the max value?

Comment: How many items are included in each import, how often do the imports run, and have you run the numbers to work out *when you're likely to exceed 2^63-1*? E.g. if you're importing 10 million records on an hourly basis, you have approximately 105 million years in which to address the issue (assuming you started at 1)

Answer (score 0):

When I try to to exceed the max identity value I get this error:

`SQL Error [90151] [22000]: Sequence value has exceeded valid range in sequence object AUTOINCREMENT`

Sequences can be configured to wrap around if you want though:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/seq1.html